# Adding List from Model to Controller (MVC) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Model Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace testing.Models
{
    public class SchemaDefinition
    {
        public List<RecordInfo> Input { get; set; }
        public List<RecordInfo> Output { get; set; }
    }
    public class RecordInfo
    {
      public string RecordId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<FieldInfo> FieldInfo { get; set; }

    }

   
    public class FieldInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int End { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
var SchemaDefintion = new SchemaDefinition();
                   
                    

                    for (int Currentsheet = 1; Currentsheet <= WorksheetCount; Currentsheet=Currentsheet+1)
                    {

                        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[Currentsheet];
                        string SheetName = worksheet.Name;

                        if (SheetName.Substring(0, 2) != "A" || SheetName.Substring(0, 2) != "B")
                        {
                            //Error that invalid excel sheet
                        }

                        Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

                       

                       var ListFields = new List<FieldInfo>();

                        for (int row = 2; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
                        {

                           

                            var Fieldproperties = new FieldInfo {Name = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text, Description = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text,
                                                                        Length =Convert.ToInt32(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 3]).Text),
                                                                        Start=Convert.ToInt32( ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 4]).Text),
                                                                       End=Convert.ToInt32( ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 5]).Text),
                                                                      Format= ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 6]).Text
                                                                  };

                       ListFields.Add(Fieldproperties);
                        }

                           
                        SchemaDefintion.Input.Add(new testing.Models.RecordInfo { RecordId = "A", Name = "header", Description = "description", FieldInfo = ListFields });
```

When i put debug in my code it's throws an error at the line below

```
SchemaDefintion.Input.Add(new testing.Models.RecordInfo { RecordId = "A", Name = "header", Description = "description", FieldInfo = ListFields });`
```

The Error descriptions as

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ________________________________________ Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
> during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
> stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Input and Output properties was not initialized, so, both are null when you try to add...

Comment: How can we initialize the input/output properties for my MVC code.I'm just new to this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tistkle

I just initialize the Corresponding Input  and output in my **Controller code**

```
SchemaDefintion.Input = new List<RecordInfo>();

SchemaDefintion.Output = new List<RecordInfo>();
```

Now it's working fine.